# Build hash of lists, as for "all tags for id" with perl dbi

Tags: mysql, perl

I searched around the `dbi` docs and googled around but could not find if there was a (dbi) native way of building up a hash of lists. The closest I can think of is `fetchall_hashref` but that overwrites the results, only giving me whatever the last pair was. To clarify, my table is a list of pairs of something like "id, tag". I wish to group all rows by id and return a hash where the key is the id, and the "value" is a (ref to) the list of all its tags. So in the case of:

```
id1, tag1
id1, tag2
id2, tag3
id2, tag1
```

I want to get:

```
{'id1' => ['tag1', 'tag2'],
 'id2' => ['tag3', 'tag1'] }
```

Is this possible? If not, what is the best (most efficient) way to do this non-natively? The obvious approach would be to just do a fetchall_* + push() combo, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my current approach:

```
my $ret = {};
foreach (@{ $sth->fetchall_arrayref(  ) }) { # returns ref to array
    push  @{ $ret->{ $_->[0] } }, $_->[1] ;
    }
return $ret;
```

In case it is useful to someone out there, while we wait to see if there's a better way of doing this.

---

Edit:

I found another approach, which is to use `GROUP_CONCAT` in MySQL for the "tags", joined with a unique character, which then you `split()` in perl. The query would be something like:

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(tag, '|')
FROM mytable
GROUP BY tag
```

Then in perl:

```
my $ret = {};
foreach (@{ $sth->fetchall_arrayref(  ) }) { # returns ref to array
    push  @{ $ret->{ $_->[0] } }, split("|", $_->[1]) ;
    }
return $ret;
```

Untested code, so standard warnings apply.

The only advantage I see is that this returns less rows from the db, and so you have less iterations of the foreach. Maybe someone can profile this code and let us know if there are any significant speed differences in the approaches.